# jsf4birt: Is exadel.org dead?

Tags: jsf, birt

I want to test jsf4birt in my web application. The [tutorial](http://developer.actuate.com/deployment-center/integrating-birt-into-applications/birt-with-jsf/) at the actuate website tells me to download the jsf4birt Library at [exadel.org](http://exadel.org/jsf4birt) but exadel.org is not available at all.

Does anyone know, if the jsf4birt project is continued in any way - and where - or is the project not supported anymore?

Cheers, Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last working archive of their website dates back to 2014-03-26. Either way, seems like jsf4birt only supported up to JSF 1.2. Project seems to be discontinued.

Comment: Thank you Thrax. Where did you get this information from? I cannot access exadel.org. The server seems to be down (which is the reason I asked if it is dead).

Comment: I used Archive.org : https://archive.org/. Then i saw the name of "maxkatz" and I googled it. I found some blog about JSF1.2 and JSF4Birt

Comment: Ah, I see. I already found the "maxkatz" blog before. It is from 2010 and also refers to the non existing website "exadel.org". Seems to me either, that they do not continue this project. Thanks a lot!